# how to dynamically create struct instances and store them in a list?

Tags: c#

I have a hw assignment that says to create a win form app that lets the user click on any day of the month of January 2018. Then display four pieces of data about the weather of that day.

steps:

First read the weather.txt file which holds each days weather data(e.g 1/13/2018;0;36;13) and split the 4 pieces of data into four fields of a struct and create an instance of that day. Then store that day in a list.

My problem:

How do I create an instance of a struct dynamically like that. The only thing coming to my mind is looping through each day of the month changing the var name incrementally like `[structObj] d[i] = new [structObj](string date, int precipitation, int temp);` where [i] changes the name with the loop and then I've easily populated a months worths of structs into my list. This doesn't work:(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Weather_data
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        struct WeatherData
        {
            private string date { get; set; }
            private int precipitation { get; set; }
            private int hiTemp { get; set; }
            private int lowTemp { get; set; }

            public WeatherData(string date, int precipitation, int hiTemp, int lowTemp)
            {
                this.date = date;
                this.precipitation = precipitation;
                this.hiTemp = hiTemp;
                this.lowTemp = lowTemp;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //change FILE PATH for weather.txt here--->
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sethr\Desktop\C#\M9SPabst\Weather data\Weather data\weather.txt");
            
            for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] data = lines[i].Split(';');

                WeatherData d = new WeatherData(data[0],
                                     Convert.ToInt32(data[1]),
                                     Convert.ToInt32(data[2]),
                                     Convert.ToInt32(data[3]));
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what exactly does "not working" mean? You do not put your new instance into a list, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the FileReadsAllLines reads corretly you would add the list to your code. And then add each element. You will need a component to display the list in the UI.

```
List<WeatherData> wheatherDataList = new List<WeatherData>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //change FILE PATH for weather.txt here--->
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sethr\Desktop\C#\M9SPabst\Weather data\Weather data\weather.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] data = lines[i].Split(';');
        
        WeatherData d = new WeatherData(data[0],
                             Convert.ToInt32(data[1]),
                             Convert.ToInt32(data[2]),
                             Convert.ToInt32(data[3]));
        wheatherDataList.Add(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this but looking at this where 'd' is the new struct instance. And every one after that is also similarly named 'd' wouldn't that throw an error?

Comment: This worked, thank you but before I check  mark it can you please tell me why all the instances that get created are allowed to have the save variable name . I'm a noob little of what I know is JavaScript but how can this be? looking at the list of structs I can only see its fields, wher's the var name??

Comment: the WeatherData d name declaration only exists durring the current for loop interation. You couldn't declare another WeatherData d instance inside the for codeblock. You could write wheatherDataList.Add(new WeatherData(data[0],
                             Convert.ToInt32(data[1]),
                             Convert.ToInt32(data[2]),
                             Convert.ToInt32(data[3]))); that would result in the same code but harder to read.